# Owl carousel item content z-index

Tags: css, z-index, owl-carousel

I have a issue with setting z-index of owl carousel `item` content over fixed overlay.

Every carousel item has background image and text content.

Fixed overlay should be over item (background image), but not over item content.

Fixed overlay cant be part of carousel item, it has to stay static when slides are changing.

**What i have:**[image]

**What i want:**[image]

I tried all different approaches, from various z-index values together with different positioning of all elements, but with no success.

**HTML, PHP:**

```
<div class="intro">

    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php
    foreach ($Services as $key => $service) {
        echo '<div class="item ' . $key .'" style="background: url(' . $css_path . $service->img_mainpage . '">';
            echo '<div class="hdr_main"><a href="/' . slug($service->title) . '">' . $service->title . '</a></div>';
            echo '<span class="about">' . $service->about . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-overlay">
        <?php include(__DIR__ . '/../../assets/gui/mainpage-polygon.svg'); ?>  
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.intro {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(0, 121, 201);
}

div.intro .fixed-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.owl-carousel {
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 2;
}

.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 13%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
}

.item .hdr_main a {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share css / html code?

Comment: @CarlosMartins Done

Answer (score 4):

```css
.item {
    z-index: 1;
}

.owl-carousel {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

try this one

Comment: This works but owl carousel stops working

Answer (score 3):

With `z-index` you also need `position: relative` or `absolute`. Try setting that to the parent `div` that holds the owl carousel. I also faced this situation with owl carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply the format just to .item class

```
.item {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but it wont work, i have tried it already. `.owl-carousel` has z-index and it overwrites z-index of item and its content. And I also need .item to be under `.fixed-overlay`

Comment: z-index is only applied when the container is also marked as position: relative/absolute. If it is not possible in the element you are trying to bring on top you should do it in the other elements with a lower z-index.

Comment: I tied to manipulate with positions of all elements inside carousel and with different z-index values, but still no success.

Comment: Not sure what happen when you say 'no success'.
How about override .fixed-overlay {z-index: 3 !important;}